# SQL Server equivalent of this MySQL sort clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to sort my results based on two varchar columns `COL_A` and `COL_B`.

If the value of `COL_A` is `('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`, I want it the appear at the top, otherwise I want it to appear at the bottom. Then, I want to do a simple lexicographical sort on COL_B. In MySQL I would have done it like this:

```
ORDER BY IF(COL_A IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'), 0, 1), COL_B
```

But this doesn't work in SQL Server 2008. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `case when` instead of IF in the query which you tried.

```
ORDER BY (Case When COL_A IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') Then 0 Else 1 End), COL_B
```

Put this in place of query which you tried.

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx

**Syntax And Example:**

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/

**Tutorial Might Helpful:**

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php